# Sharepoint not letting iis to trigger cmd.exe using processstartinfo

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis, windows-server-2008-r2, worker-process

Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Sharepoint page : SharePoint 3.0

**Set the application pool identity to use the Local System**

Logged in as administrator

the code works fine on the above system but when tried on the same but enterprise server(Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise) - cmd.exe is not triggered

```
        Dim cmds As Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        Dim cmdr As Diagnostics.Process

        cmds = New Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        cmds .FileName = "cmd.exe"
        cmds .Verb = "runas"
        cmds .WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files\Menton\Setup"
        cmds .UseShellExecute = True
        cmds .RedirectStandardOutput = False
        cmds .RedirectStandardInput = False
        cmds .RedirectStandardError = False
        cmds .CreateNoWindow = True


        cmdr = Process.Start(cmds)
        cmdr.WaitForExit()
```

Works on  Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
It doesn't work on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise **with all same settings and configurations**

Comment: executed by web service

Comment: yeah it is hosted on sp

Comment: Try elevating code block.. `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges...`

Comment: thanks. I have come across that before too. But im a bit confused why would that work on one server with same privileges and not on another with same settings n configs.. ?

Comment: I suspect permission issue. The user account which you used on the other server might have proper permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services uses impersonation so that code running within a executes with the identity and permissions of the current user.

However, occasionally your code must call restricted methods within the Windows SharePoint Services object model even though the request is initiated by a nonprivileged user. In such cases you must be able to elevate the privilege of your code as it executes on the Web server.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(AddressOf MyElevatedMethod)

Sub MyElevatedMethod()
    'Your code goes here
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the library should I import to use SPSecurity in vb?

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

Comment: Sorry I need to run specific code block within a private function... how can i do that?